# Dialog visible without app. on alt tab

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have developed Swing application in which I have used `JDialog` to show popup.

But the problem is when I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> it shows only the dialog not the application.  I also tried the modal for dialog.

My requirement is when the dialog opened on application and I press the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> key it   switch to another X application and again when I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> key it display dialog opened   on my application.  Currently it shows dialog opened but alone *not with application.*

How I can meet this requirement using `JDialog`?

Here is sample code

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
*$Id$
*/
public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setSize(300, 200);
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        final JButton button = new JButton("click here to open dialog");
        final ProductDialog dialog = new ProductDialog();
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e)
            {
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);
        jFrame.add(panel);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

### And The dialog is as under

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ProductDialog extends JDialog
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ProductDialog()
    {
        this.add(new JPanel().add(new JLabel("Test")));
        this.setSize(150, 100);
        this.setModal(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Here is an image of the visual effect of a small app. that is currently displaying a security dialog in <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> on Windows 7.  The app. itself is already visible on-screen, though the security dialog (upper left) is all that is shown in the smaller icons.

[image]

Comment: Please post the code where you instantiate and open the dialog.

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about JDialog, keys shortcut alt + tab and empty applications window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the parent window of the dialog to the `Frame` of your application.

Small example:

```
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestDialog {

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestDialog.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JButton button = new JButton("Click me to open dialog");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Window parentWindow = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(button);
                JDialog dialog = new JDialog(parentWindow);
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(button);
                dialog.setModal(true);
                dialog.add(new JLabel("A dialog"));
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestDialog().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: --**I want only one window of whole application with dialog to be display   in alt + tab window, not different like one is application and one is dialog.**

Comment: @Tejas When I use ALT+TAB, I only see a single window for my Java application. I don't understand how my answers fails your requirements. And when you look at your answer, I don't see how it differs from mine.

Answer (score 0):

**I have pass the parent Frame to the Dialog as under.**

```
final ProductDialog dialog = new ProductDialog(jFrame);
```

**And set it as under

Call the constructor of super class with parent window as argument and set the modality type of dialog and it's work for me.**

```
import java.awt.Dialog;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ProductDialog extends JDialog
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ProductDialog(final JFrame jFrame)
    {
        super(jFrame);
        this.add(new JPanel().add(new JLabel("Test")));
        this.setSize(150, 100);
        this.setModal(true);
        this.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
    }
}
```

**This is just sample example that I have created for testing.**